# How can I put many script-generated records in PostgreSQL quickly from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, database-performance

The following code, which inserts 200,000 records into PostgreSQL server from node.js, is taking about 17 minutes on my laptop PC, which feels horribly slow.

```js
var pg = require('pg');
var Client = pg.Client;
var async = require('async');

var client = new Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

var rollback = function(client) {
  client.query('ROLLBACK', function() {
    client.end();
    process.kill();
  });
};

client.query('BEGIN',function(err,result){
  if(err){ console.error(err); rollback(client);};
  async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
      client.query('DROP INDEX idx',function(err,result){
        client.query('TRUNCATE TABLE tbl',function(err,result){
          async.forEach(values,function(value,valueNext){
            client.query('INSERT INTO tbl ('
                         + 'col1,'
                         + 'col2) VALUES ($1,$2)',[
                           value,
                           generatedSomething(value)
                         ],function(err){
                           valueNext();
                         });
          },function(err,result){
            if(err){ console.error(err); rollback(client);cb(false);return;};
            client.query('CREATE INDEX idx ON tbl',function(err,result){
              cb(null);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  },
],function(err){
  client.query('COMMIT', client.end.bind(client));
});
```

There are some strategies I've applied to speed up.

- **Drop all indices before insertion, create it after all insertion is done** ... ok
- **Use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE FROM`** ... ok
- **Use `COPY FROM` instead of `INSERT INTO`** ... not done

It seems that using `COPY FROM` instead of `INSERT INTO` will make effect, but it's used for imported CSV files, not for script-generated values.

So, does it mean that **exporting script-generated values to temporary CSV file, and importing values using `COPY FROM`**, is the most effictive way to insert values into PostgreSQL quickly?

Comment: Why are you using waterfall if you're only passing 1 function in the array?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100807/node-postgres-with-massive-amount-of-queries

Answer (score 1):

[copyFrom](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-copy-from) will return a [WritableStream](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_writable_stream) that you can append your values to as CSV, like:

```js
var stream = client.copyFrom("COPY tbl (col1, col2) FROM STDIN WITH CSV");
stream.on('close', function() {
  client.query("COMMIT");
});
stream.on('error', rollback);
async.forEach(values, function(value, valueNext) {
  stream.write(value + "," + generatedSomething(value) + "\n");
});
stream.end();
```

Of course you will need to properly escape your values